# Error 404 : css page can't load in JSP

Tags: java, css, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

I have trouble with CSS in JSP pages.

CSS files are not loaded in any page.

I have this JSP page which is a registration form for a student.

I have a page works correctly but that page has no information from my database.

The rest of pages include some lines and some data from the database.

I really don't know where the problem is so I need your help :(

**Student form :**

```
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="tables.Optionn"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <base href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}">
        <link href="Style/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="Style/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="Style/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="Style/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <% List<Optionn> option = (List<Optionn>) request.getAttribute("option_list");%>

        <title>Etudiant</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container" id="registration_form">
            <form method="post"  class="form-login"  action="//localhost:8086/GestionPfe/reg_etudiant">
                <h2  class="form-login-heading"  >ajouter un Etudiant!</h2>
                <div class="login-wrap">
                    Option:  <br> <select name="opt"     class="form-control">
                        <%for (Optionn tempop : option) {%>
                        <option value=<%=tempop.getIdOption()%> > <%=tempop.getNomOption()%></option> 
                        <%}%>
                    </select><br>
                    Nom:  <br>  <input name="nom_etudiant" type="text" class="form-control">
                    <br>
                    Prenomt:  <br> <input name="prenom_etudiant" type="text" class="form-control">
                    <br>
                    Niveau:  <br> <input name="niveau_etudiant" type="text" class="form-control">
                    <br>
                    Date De Naissance:  <br><input name="date_naissance_etudiant" type="date" class="form-control">
                    <br>
                    Numero D'inscription:  <br> <input name="num_inscription_etudiant" type="text" class="form-control">
                    <br>
                    Adresse:  <br> <input name="adresse_etudiant" type="text" class="form-control">
                    <br>
                    Email:  <br><input name="email_etudiant" type="email" class="form-control">
                    <br>
                    Mot De Pass:  <br><input name="mot_de_pass_etudiant" type="password" class="form-control">
                    <br>
                    Telephone:  <br><input name="telephone_etudiant" type="text" class="form-control">
                    <br>

                    <button type="submit"   class="btn btn-theme btn-block"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> SIGN IN</button>

                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Student Servlet :**

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException,IOException{

   Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
   session.beginTransaction();


   String op= request.getParameter("opt");

   String nom_etudiant= request.getParameter("nom_etudiant");

   String prenom_etudiant= request.getParameter("prenom_etudiant");

   String niveau_etudiant= request.getParameter("niveau_etudiant");

   String num_inscription_etudiant= request.getParameter("num_inscription_etudiant");

   String date_naissance_etudiant= request.getParameter("date_naissance_etudiant");

   String adresse_etudiant = request.getParameter("adresse_etudiant");

   String email_etudiant = request.getParameter("email_etudiant");

   String mot_de_pass_etudiant = request.getParameter("mot_de_pass_etudiant");

   String telephone_etudiant = request.getParameter("telephone_etudiant");

   try {
      int idop=Integer.parseInt(op);
      int tel=Integer.parseInt(telephone_etudiant);

      SimpleDateFormat simpledate=new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd");
      Date birthdayDate = simpledate.parse(date_naissance_etudiant);

      Optionn opt = new Optionn();
      opt = (Optionn) session.get(Optionn.class,idop);

      Etudiant etudiant=new Etudiant(opt,nom_etudiant,prenom_etudiant,niveau_etudiant, mot_de_pass_etudiant,num_inscription_etudiant,birthdayDate,adresse_etudiant,email_etudiant,tel);

     session.save(etudiant);
     session.getTransaction().commit();
     session.close();

     response.sendRedirect("Jsp/home.jsp");

   } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(reg_agent.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }

  }
}
```

Comment: check value of  `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` and add screenshot of your project structure

Comment: What application server is hosting your content?

Answer (score 1):

Add ".." to all your path,

```
<link href="../Style/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: why should i put  ..  ?

Comment: Would't that only work if the "Style" folder was one up in the directory structure from the parent?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 try {
      int idop=Integer.parseInt(op);
      int tel=Integer.parseInt(telephone_etudiant);

      SimpleDateFormat simpledate=new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd");
      Date birthdayDate = simpledate.parse(date_naissance_etudiant);

      Optionn opt = new Optionn();
      opt = (Optionn) session.get(Optionn.class,idop);

      Etudiant etudiant=new Etudiant(opt,nom_etudiant,prenom_etudiant,niveau_etudiant, mot_de_pass_etudiant,num_inscription_etudiant,birthdayDate,adresse_etudiant,email_etudiant,tel);

     session.save(etudiant);
     session.getTransaction().commit();
     session.close();

    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("Jsp/home.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);



   } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(reg_agent.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks Sir! this is  Answers _very helpful to me.